# joomla 3.x external database

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am trying to get Joomla to connect to an external database, I have read [this tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database), which tells you what to do, but where do you put the code? As I am new to Joomla, I have tried to put it in the configuration.php, all the template index.php, I'm not sure if I need to create a module or plugin.

Comment: You need to provide more information on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @jonasfh I was trying to separate an existing installation into app and database.  I apologize for that not being clear.

Comment: ?? An existing joomla installation? Do you want to fetch some data from another server, or just get all the joomla data from another server? What do you want to achieve. What have you tried so far that did not work?Any error messages? Some code please! Be specific! Read the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jonasfh I was being as specific as i could be with the limited knowlege of joomla that I have. There was an existing joomal installation and I wanted to move the existing data from a local database to an external database. I read the tutorial on how to connect to an external database, but evidently I don't understand enough about how joomla works for it to be simple for me to do. so what to me seemed like a simple task for what I'm used to is more complex in nature. I appreciate your responses, but decided to start from scratch instead.

Comment: You did not say you wanted to "move the existing data from a local database to an external database". You said you wanted "to get Joomla to connect to an external database", which could mean almost anything. Try to specify your problem better and you'll get much better response here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what the purpose of accessing the database is and when you want to do it.

In some cases you would use a plugin. Specifically if accessing the database would happen before or after some event, like logging in or a page load then a plugin. This is especially true if it is invisible to the user.  If it is content that will appear on designated pages and will have a layout, then probably a module.

Comment: thank you @Elin for your response. This was more complex for me than I anticipated.